# Why am I not getting output in terminal nor it is creating a .class file in java during execution?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

//this is a simple program of java[the image is from vs code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc5Ar.png)

```
public class Hello {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

}

Comment: Did you save the file Hello.java first?

Comment: `$?` is the result of the last command. If you didn't execute a command before checking it, what is its value?

Answer (score 0):

The image shows a Powershell script on the console.
Unless I am missing something here, all that needs to be done is for the java file to be compiled to generate a class file that can be executed by the runtime.

```
> javac Hello.java
> java Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the *Code Runner* extension installed, and use **Run Code** to run the code. If your project structure has multiple layers of folders, running code with **Run Code** in deeper folders will fail.

For a better working experience, please use the **Run Java** of the java extension itself to run the code. You can use the methods in the following two pictures.

[image]

[image]